# '&quot;' instead of normal quotes ("") in returning XML from Jersey

Tags: java, xml-serialization, jaxb, jersey

i've got the following problem. I've got web-service that uses Jersey, it can produce 2 kinds of returning data - XML and JSON.

```
@GET
@Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
```

Returning data also contains a string that have quotes `""`, if returning data type is JSON, than everything works properly - string with normal quotes `""` are returned, but in case returning data type is XML, than string with `&quot;` is returned.

The problem is that on the client side string with normal `""` quotes is expected. Help please to overcome this problem.

Expected String example:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

Comment: Why is this a problem? A XML parser should interpret `&quot;` as the quote character. Jersey probably encodes everything it can even in element content, instead of only encoding quotes in attribute content. (Either just to be sure or to make the code simpler.)

Comment: It's not a problem. It's correct XML behavior, or at least, from what you've said it *sounds* correct. Perhaps an example of the output you think is incorrect would help.

Comment: I understand that it is correct behavior, but on client side normal string with normal ("") quotes is expected. So this is a problem =(

Comment: Ah, missed your edit. "The client's XML parser is dumb and can't be made not dumb" is an important detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at: [Can I force JAXB not to convert " into &quot;, for example, when marshalling to XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506663/can-i-force-jaxb-not-to-convert-into-quot-for-example-when-marshalling-to)

(JAX-RS uses JAXB).

I know that &quot; and &apos; can be problematic as I have seen some older XML systems do weird things (including the venerable IE 7).

Comment: Thanks for advice, but how can i use that method regarding to my web-service that uses jersey context ?

Comment: @VladimirSelin Jersey implements JAX-RS which uses JAXB for XML (which you should know).

Comment: I know it=). The question was - if you can advice me the way i can 'tell' Jersey which JAXBFactory it should use, as in my app. jersey do everything by itself. Thanks in advance)

Comment: Your making me work over time here :). About one second of googling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034673/how-to-customise-the-xml-output-of-a-jersey-jaxb-serialisation

Comment: I'm very very sorry. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

XML is used for program-to-program communication. `&quot;` inside the character data has the same meaning as `"`.

Do you experience some problems in the program where you're trying to parse the "returned data"?

Comment: Yes, normal string with normal quotes is expected on the client side.

Comment: @VladimirSelin Expected by what? What exactly is running on the client side and why is it unable to parse the well-formed XML? You're solving the wrong problem; the actual problem is not the server-side replacing quotes with `&quot;` (which gives you a valid XML) but the client-side failing to process such an XML. It also might be a hint to some deeper problems on a client-side, such as vulnerability to various injections.