# Setting XML Headers in Jersey response

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jersey

I have couple of web-services implemented via Jersey/Jaxb which are sending XML response as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I want to edit this header and to include `standalone="yes"`. I know i can use `marshaller.setProperty(..)` method to over come this but It will be a lot of work to change the response code for EVERY response being sent from the project.

Is there a better way to achieve this in the project ? Setting some custom Jaxb property file or some configuration or something ?

---

**EDIT**

So I managed to achieve what i want to but i am not sure if this is the right way to do it. I wrote a custom marshaller resolver and override the xml header.

```
@Provider
public class JaxbMarshallerResolver implements ContextResolver<Marshaller> 
{

    @Override
    public Marshaller getContext(Class<?> type) 
    {
        Marshaller marshaller;
        try
        {
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(type);
            marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration", Boolean.FALSE);
            marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>");
        }
        catch (JAXBException je)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(je);
        }
        return marshaller;
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to achieve it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034673/how-to-customise-the-xml-output-of-a-jersey-jaxb-serialisation ?

Comment: ^ This is not something which will answer my question